# Tikz Hierarchical Chart - Branching Children

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none},
level distance=45pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,minimum width=\widthof{Janet Botwood}}]
 \Tree 
[ .{Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager} 
[ .{Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager} ] 
 [ .{Janet Botwood\\Head of Care} ] 
 [ .{Sunny Bell\\Head of Care}  ] ] 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to make Anita & Ruth on the same branch level. Also, how would I make children branches of Janet and Sunny?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Maybe you add a little drawing of what you want. Makes it easier. Should Ruth and Anita be on first level? Or second? Should Janet have children *and* Sunny or do you want to connect them like in a family tree?

Comment: Anita and Ruth should be on first level like grandfather and grandmother. Janet should have three children and Sunny should have three children separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees are not meant for multiple "parents". I am not sure, if I got you right, but you could just put the two first names into one single node:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
        {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                -- +(0,-8pt)
                -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
        blank/.style={draw=none},
        level distance=45pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,minimum width=\widthof{Janet Botwood}}]
    \Tree [.\node(grands)[rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=2]{Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager \nodepart{second} Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager};  
    [ .{Janet Botwood\\Head of Care} A B C  ] 
    [ .{Sunny Bell\\Head of Care} D E F ] ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: forest tree]

This uses the power `forest` package. The trick involved in getting Ruth and Anita on the same level is to make them children of a `phantom` node, since the tree must have a single root.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north
  }
  [, phantom, for children={fit=band}
    [Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager
      [Janet Botwood\\Head of Care
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]
      ]
      [Sunny Bell\\Head of Care
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]
      ]
    ]
    [Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Or like this?

[image: different forest tree]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north
  }
  [, phantom, for children={fit=band}
    [Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager
      [Janet Botwood\\Head of Care
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]
      ]
    ]
    [Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager
      [Sunny Bell\\Head of Care
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```